# ASP.NET MVC Model validation not working on ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have ViewModel that has inside a Model and some extra properties. There are validation on the model and on the property, but when executed, only validation on Model are checked, validation in the property is ignored.

The Model:

```
 [MetadataType(typeof(Customer_Validation))]
 public partial class Customer
 {
 }

 public class Customer_Validation
 {
     [Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter your First Name")]
     public string FirstName { get; set; }

     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your Last name")]
     public string LastName { get; set; }

     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Sorry, e-mail cannot be empty")]
     [Email(ErrorMessage="Invalid e-mail")]
     public string Email { get; set; }
 }
```

The ViewModel

```
 public class RegisterViewModel
 {
     public Customer NewCustomer { get; private set; }

     [Required(ErrorMessage="Required")]
     public string Password { get; private set; }

     public RegisterViewModel(Customer customer, string password)
     {
         NewCustomer = customer;
         Password = password;
     }
 }
```

The Controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
     Customer customer = new Customer();    
     RegisterViewModel model = new RegisterViewModel(customer, "");    
     return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Customer newCustomer, string password)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         try
         {
             // code to save to database, redirect to other page
         }
         catch
         {
             RegisterViewModel model = new RegisterViewModel(newCustomer, password);
             return View(model);
         }
     }
     else
     {
         RegisterViewModel model = new RegisterViewModel(newCustomer, password);
         return View(model);
     }
}
```

The View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>First Name:</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NewCustomer.FirstName)</td>
    <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.NewCustomer.FirstName)</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Last Name:</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NewCustomer.LastName)</td>
    <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.NewCustomer.LastName)</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>E-mail:</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NewCustomer.Email)</td>
    <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.NewCustomer.Email)</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Password:</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password)</td>
    <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)</td>
   </tr>
  </table>

  <input type="submit" value="Register" />
 }
```

If I submit the form leaving Password empty it let go through. If I leave empty the Customer fields it do show the errors (except for the password field)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's normal. Your POST controller action takes `Customer` as parameter and not the view model. The validation is performed by the model binder, so when the model binder tries to bind the Customer object from request parameters it will invoke the validation. Your POST action needs to take the view model as parameter if you want the validation to be performed on this view model. Currently all you do with this view model inside the post action is to call the constructor and calling the constructor doesn't trigger any validation at all.

So your POST action should become:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(RegisterViewModel newCustomer)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         // code to save to database, redirect to other page
     }
     else
     {
         return View(newCustomer);
     }
}
```

Notice how you don't need to pass the password as second action argument as it is already part of your view model.

Comment: Thats sounds logic and can help me fix it. I will make the other properties validation inside the controller by separate until finding a best solution to use model validation for this case. Thanks a lot.

Comment: How do you make the View to pass a ViewModel to the post controller? I had tried before and it shows "nullable parameter" error since the form receive the ViewModel but when post back it breaks it down to each models inside the ViewModel so it cannot match the signature on post controller, and then the controller sets null to the ViewModel parameter, that forces me in post controller to get each model as separate parameter instead of one single parameter for the ViewModel.

Comment: @Nestor, to make a view pass a ViewModel to a controller you could include a `<form>` in this view and inside put text fields corresponding to properties of your ViewModel that will be passed. Remember that only what's sent in the request will be bound to the ViewModel.

Comment: I mean, a ViewModel like my example, the ViewModel contains a Customer object and one string Password, so far I cannot get View pass something like that into one single ViewModel, in other words, complex model like this cannot be bounded by the View, only bind the inside Customer object model and the string password. If I write my post controller like Create(ViewModel model) I get a "nullable parameter" error, only Create(Customer newCustomer, string password) is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because the setter on your password property is set to `private set`. All the setters on the rest of your customer fields are public setters. When a property does not have a setter inspection for a valid value is not required.

Comment: When model is binded the constructor is called, constructor is in charge of setting those private properties, no need to access those properties from outside the class. Reason is like Darin says about only Model is being called, not ViewModel so no binding for ViewModel so not validation triggered.